# How to test React function that has api request in it?

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

I have a function like so in a react component. How do I test a successful request and an unsuccessful request?

```
deleteQuestion(id) {
  axios.delete('/api/questions/' + id)
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({message: "Deletion Successful!"});
    }).catch(error => {
      var errorMessage = 'Question not deleted: ' + error.response.data.message;
      this.setState({error: errorMessage});
    });
}
```

And I was thinking of doing something like this for the testing but this obviously does not work. Basically, the console.log and assertion in the final function do not run.

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import axios from 'axios';
import axios from 'axios';
import QuestionList from './QuestionList';
import sinon from 'sinon';


beforeEach(function () {
  // import and pass your custom axios instance to this method
  moxios.install()
})

afterEach(function () {
  // import and pass your custom axios instance to this method
  moxios.uninstall()
})

it('should modals and <table>', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<QuestionList/>);
  wrapper.instance().deleteQuestion()
  moxios.wait(function () {
      let request = moxios.requests.mostRecent()
      request.respondWith({
        status: 200,
        response: [
          { id: 1, question: 'Fred', answer: 'Flintstone' },
          { id: 2, question: 'Wilma', answer: 'Flintstone' }
        ]
      }).then(function () {
        console.log('hello')
        expect(wrapper.state().message).to.equal('Deletion Successful');
        done()
      })
    })
});
```

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some mock http server library. For example https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-http-server

Comment: I updated the answer with more details, the main problem is that the request is not being sent in the wrapper.instance().deleteQuestion() call, it is still not working however.